# Why would Discontinuous Conduction Mode be desirable for an LED driver?

Tags: led, led-driver, flyback, power-factor-correction

I saw this press release where DCM was listed as a feature for a new Infineon driver chip.

[image]
Source: [led-professional.com](https://www.led-professional.com/products/led-driver-ics-modules/infineon-presents-xdpl8221-the-device-for-advanced-smart-and-connected-led-driver?utm_source=LED%20professional%20-%20FREE%20Information%20Service&utm_campaign=2453b0b740-LED%20professional%20Newsletter%20%28LpN%29-Feb15%2C%202018_COPY&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_ff8d2246a5-2453b0b740-%5BLIST_EMAIL_ID%5D&ct=t%28LED%20professional%20Newsletter%20%28LpN%29-Feb15%2C%202018_COPY%29)

I'm involved in LED driver design for Horticulture where DCM is undesirable.

In what case would DCM be desirable for any LED lighting application?

Or is DCM in reference to something other than the output to the LED? Still, if so, why is DCM desirable in any LED driver?

**UPDATE:**  Why DCM is used in the power stage was answered in the comments.  I still wonder if DCM is ever desirable in the output to the LEDs? This secondary question is not related to the linked AC powered LED driver.

---

Datasheet defines operating modes on Page 11 and has an appendix with definitions of related terminology.

Section 3.1.8.5 Other PFC Protections, mentions CCM.
Section 3.2 Flyback Controller Features, mentions DCM.

Datasheet:  [XDPL8221 Digital PFC+Flyback Controller IC](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-XDPL8221-DS-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46266f85d6301670d68764e3679)

[image]

Comment: DCM is a common thing in switching power supplies.  They switch to DCM when the output load is too low for the PWM regulation to keep the output voltage steady.  I don't know why that would be a bad thing for your grow lights.

Comment: @JRE research has found any type of lighting strobe effect will adversely affect growth.  This is why I am unfamiliar with DCM. And I always use a DC-DC buck driver or an off the shelf Mean Well CC driver.

Comment: @JRE The output to the LEDs can be CCM or DCM.  I assumed that DCM was a cost saving measure for cheap LED drivers, e.g. driving an LED with an FET and PWM.

Comment: You've linked to a switching regulator.  It varies the on time to control the the output voltage or current.  DCM is used when the regular switching frequency (at the lowest on time) is still too much for the attached load

Comment: @JRE if you look at the schematic you will see the output marked as LED+ and LED-.  And the press release was on led-professional.com.  I assumed the DCM in this release is related to the power stage, but I have always wondered if DCM was ever desirable in the LED output as well.

Comment: It looks like you're summing two operation modes in *"Datasheet defines operating modes on Page 11 and has an appendix with definitions of related terminology."* But page 11 **only** applies to the PFC, not to the Flyback. The operating modes of the PFC are not (directly) relevant to how power to the LED's is being supplied. The operating modes of the flyback dictate it.

Comment: @Huisman Thank you.  That is what I had assumed.  There is a secondary question, whether (and why) DCM,  could ever be desirable in the output to the LEDs.

Comment: @Misunderstood You write, "research has found any type of lighting strobe effect will adversely affect growth." I would like to know what research, exactly. I find just the opposite in recent studies by NASA for artificial plant growth lighting in space. Different wavelengths are involved in aspects of the molecular cycles, some that are needed to reset things back. Turns out the cells are "stressed" somewhat less if there is a relaxation of certain wavelengths during the cycle at certain times. If I'm reading them, correctly. (Orders of dozens of microseconds, by the way.)

Comment: @jonk I asked Dr. Thomas Colquhoun a research professor in the Horticulture Dept at the University of Florida about turning LEDs off and on to save energy. His reply was that studies have been done on this topic and it was found that the plants were adversely affected. He did not cite any specific study. This made sense to me because the reaction time to convert a photon is several nanoseconds and the output of the light reactions must be matched with the demands of metabolism. As plants have evolved in sunlight it makes sense that the photon stream should not be periodically interrupted.

Comment: @Misunderstood New NASA experiments would appear to differ. If you want, I can cite perhaps a dozen studies or more from the last four or five years. I've been investigating these ideas because I'm planning on designing a system to test them, myself. I'm not saying NASA is 'god' here. They make mistakes like anyone else. But the research I've seen is compelling.

Comment: @jonk I would be very interested in viewing these studies.  You may send them to an email address I just created: py@eatled.com.  I am also interested in why you are interested in this topic.  I had proposed a study to Dr. Kevin Folta for trying transmitting two wavelengths (e.g. blue and red) out of phase so the plant is still adsorbing photons 100% of the time with the objective to possibly increase system efficiency.  Some drivers have a synchronous mode to reduce EMI when multiple drivers are used simultaneously so it would be simple to run them out of phase as well.

Comment: @Misunderstood My recollection is that there are more than two wavelengths involved in the complete cycle. But that's just my memory speaking, right now. I'll pull up what I can find when I get a moment. It will be perhaps at least one, maybe two days, though. I have a completely full day tomorrow. And I'm a little unsure about the following day, right now. But I'll pull what I can and send it along.

Comment: @Misunderstood I tracked down one of the NASA articles. They mention the following: 450 nm photosynthesis, 650 nm photosynthesis, 650-670 nm phytochrome Pr-state, 705–740 nm phytochrome Pfr-state, 730 nm phytochrome. And there is a lot more information about the timing involved between the absorption and use of those wavelengths, as well. Just thought I'd add a few things to go research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SMPS in DCM will not give lighting strobe effect.

> Discontinuous Conduction Mode is an operational mode of a switching power supply in which the current starts and returns to zero.

This applies to the current through **the inductor/transformer**, not to the current through the load.
The load current will have a non-zero mean value.

EDIT: additional clarification
 
Another 'proof' DCM will not give lighting strobe effect: check the grey shaded features of this driver in [led-professional.com](https://www.led-professional.com/products/led-driver-ics-modules/infineon-presents-xdpl8221-the-device-for-advanced-smart-and-connected-led-driver)

> **Target Applications:**
>   •    **Flicker-free** LED driver for indoor or outdoor applications

================================================

The IC supports so to say two SMPS, the PFC and the flyback. The following applies:

1. DCM in the **PFC stage (power stage)** is to support light load
   conditions and ensure efficient operation.
2. DCM in the **flyback** is to support light load conditions and ensure efficient operation.

So, DCM is used in both SMPS for *exactly* the same reason.

> Depending on the actual situation, the built-in digital control **(of the flyback converter)**  selects the best mode of operation. It can switch between

- QRM: quasi-resonant (when e.g. 100 LED's are connected)
- DCM: discontinuous conduction (when e.g. 10 LED's are connected)
- ABM: active burst modes. (when e.g. 1 LED is connected)

(Number of LED's is illustrative of course)

**Why would Discontinuous Conduction Mode be desirable for an LED driver?**
To have freedom to connect 1 LED one time and 100 LED's the other time, using the same LED driver having high efficiency for every type of load.

Comment: And why is that desirable?

Comment: Because otherwise you can't serve light (medium in this case) loads without getting an overvoltage. It's a must have rather than a desire.

Comment: Check @JRE 's first remark

Comment: I now understand the reason for DCM in an SMPS as stated in my update.   DCM and CCM does apply to "the current through the load".  Many LED driver chips require that the output to the LEDs operate in CCM.  Some datasheet state they can be operated in DCM.  I never understood why anyone would want the LED load run in DCM.

Comment: @HarrySvensson thanks for the edit on my typo.  As I now understand DCM in the power stage is desirable for efficiency.  The remaining question is why would DCM be desirable in the LED load which is unrelated to the DCM in the power stage.

Comment: @Misunderstood Please read the addition to the answer. I hope it becomes clearer now.

Comment: @Misunderstood DCM or CCM refers to the inductor current and not to a load current. When you buy a SMPS you have data about output voltage and current, not any mention about CCM or DCM mode. DCM is more effective, since the inductor doesn't have any superimposed DC current, so there is less waste of power due to inductor resistance.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič when the load is a constant current LED driver the terms CCM and DCM also apply to the load.  My question was about DCM in the power stage and the LED load.